# Looking for name of manga novel of boy that found exosuit on dying alien and it has great power

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult, manga

I'm trying to find a novel I read when I was in middle school. It's a manga young adult novel, where a boy finds a dying alien in a crashed ship and has the alien's suit latch onto him. It only covers his chest, but he can morph it to fit over his whole body, and he can fly, shoot guns, and have whips come from his hands. He also has super strength with the suit.

At the beginning of the novel, his father is having trouble with a mafia that wants the money they loaned him. When they try to beat up his father again, the boy intervenes and strikes the men with whips from his suit. The boy has no idea how he did it, but it makes the thugs run away. The boy and his father start trying to knock cans off a table in the backyard with the whips, but when they get far enough away he ends up blowing a hole in the fence with a gun. He has to hide his suit at school, and has to act real weird around the girl that has a crush on him.

Then somehow he gets picked up by one of the aliens of the same species. Turns out this species built these exosuits to have normal strength, since they were very weak without them. Since the boy was already normal without the suit, he now has super strength with it. He proceeds to help the aliens with their war against these other aliens in gas form that are contained in large war suits. He fights with them for a while, and is able to grab whole ships and push them together to destroy them. They end up winning the war and he goes home.

He finds out that his parents ran away from home after he left to get away from the mafia. He then goes to the mafia boss' office and forces him to let his father's debt go. Once he finds his parents again and tells them the news, he gets ambushed by a ship of the gas aliens that tracked him back to Earth. He then morphs into his full suit, kicks their ass, and throws their ship into the sun. And I think that was the end.

I know the whole story, but I can't remember the name of the novel or the name of any of the alien species for that matter. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### I believe this is [Tech Jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tech_Jacket).

> Tech Jacket is a graphic novel series about Zack, a teenager who is given a set of powered armour by a dying alien and uses it to become the hero Tech Jacket. - [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/TechJacket)

While not Manga (is it American in origin) it describes the premise that the alien suit amplifies humans significantly more than the alien race.

> According to Zack, because a human is already physically stronger than a Geldarian, he is more capable of using the tech jacket and is a natural with it. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tech_Jacket)

[image]

Comment: This is it!! Thanks a lot man, now I can get back to a good story.

Comment: is this something like _Bio Booster Armor Guyver?_